# Extend "expirationTime" in Firebase Auth "stsTokenManager" in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

**How to extend the expirationTime in the Firestore response?** Here using Firestore JavaScript SDK. And need to access accessToken too in React Native mobile development.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = firebase.auth();



export const login = (email, password) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const response = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      //console.log(response);
    
      dispatch(authenticate(response.user.uid, ""));
    
      //console.log(response.user.stsTokenManager.expirationDate, " AAA");
      
      const expirationDate = new Date(
         new Date().getTime() + parseInt(response.user.stsTokenManager.expirationTime) * 1000
       );
      
      saveDataToStorage( response.user.uid, expirationDate);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error?.message || 'Authenticating user failed');
    }
  };
};
```

**`console.log(response)` output**

```
Object {
"user": Object {
    "stsTokenManager": Object {
      "accessToken": "",
      "apiKey": "",
      "expirationTime": 1597168005772,
      "refreshToken": "",
    },
    "tenantId": null,
    "uid": "",
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the expiration time of the provided token.  It will expire 1 hour after the last refresh.  Then token will need to be refreshed again, and the new token will last another hour.  There is no alternative to this - the refresh is required for security reasons.

The Firebase Auth SDK will automatically refresh the token for signed-in users.  There is nothing you have to do to implement this.  If you want to know when the token was refreshed, you should use [onIdTokenChanged](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth#onIdTokenChanged) to set up a listener for that.

Comment: When going back from the app and use app again causes the user to again enter the credentials before expiring the token. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately, including the code that isn't working the way you expect. You should be using an auth state listener to determine if the user is signed in.

Comment: Thank you Doug :)